# Custom Sorting Javascript with A-Z set

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array which is

```
[
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'D. Drainage',
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
  'Haroon Question Group Without Show PCP',
  'D. Drainage',
  'Haroon Question Group With Show PCP',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
];
```

i want to sort it in such a way that it should return like this

```
[
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
  'D. Drainage',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
  'D. Drainage',
  'Haroon Question Group With Show PCP',
  'Haroon Question Group Without Show PCP'
]
```

It should complete the whole A-Z set and then start again from A-Z

I have tried this one but it doesn't give the desired result

```
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'D. Drainage',
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
  'Haroon Question Group Without Show PCP',
  'D. Drainage',
  'Haroon Question Group With Show PCP',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    let aIndex = parseInt(a.charAt(0), 36);
    let bIndex = parseInt(b.charAt(0), 36);
    
    if (aIndex < bIndex) return -1;
    if (aIndex > bIndex) return 1;
    
    return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

it returns something like this

```
"A. Wound Location and Measurements", 
"A. Wound Location and Measurements",
"B. Wound Bed",
"B. Wound Bed",
"C. Surrounding Tissue",
"C. Surrounding Tissue",
"D. Drainage",
"D. Drainage",
"Haroon Question Group Without Show PCP",
"Haroon Question Group With Show PCP"
```

Comment: You just want to move all the items that don't begin with `<letter>.` to the end? Everything else already seems to be sorted the way you want.

Comment: Loop through the array. If the element begins with `<letter>.` push it onto one array, otherwise push it onto a second array. Then concatenate the two arrays.

Comment: i have updated my question for better understanding

Comment: Please make an attempt and show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: yes i have included that in my question now

Comment: you can't do this with `sort()` alone. There's no way for it to do multiple groups like you want.

Comment: After you sort the array, you need to loop over it splitting it into groups.

Comment: Can the same letter have different text after it? If so, does it matter how they're ordered in the result?

Comment: Can there be different numbers of repetitions of each letter, like `ABC ABCDE ABCD`?

Comment: Yes it can be like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could distribute the entries over buckets, where there is a bucket for each letter (A-Z) and a catch-all bucket for all other entries.

Then consume these buckets in a cyclic way to populate the result array:

```js
const data = [
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'D. Drainage',
  'B. Wound Bed',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
  'Haroon Question Group Without Show PCP',
  'D. Drainage',
  'Haroon Question Group With Show PCP',
  'A. Wound Location and Measurements',
  'C. Surrounding Tissue',
];


// Split the entries in their buckets based on the starting letter:
let buckets = Array.from({length: 27}, () => []);
for (const s of data) {
    buckets[/^[A-Z]\./.test(s) ? s.charCodeAt() - 65 : 26].push(s);
}
// The last bucket is a catch-all for elements that do not match the pattern
const last = buckets.pop();

// Consume the buckets one by one in cyclic order until we have all of them
const sorted = [];
while (buckets.length) {
    buckets = buckets.filter(arr => arr.length);
    for (const bucket of buckets) {
        sorted.push(bucket.shift());
    }
}
sorted.push(...last); // Add the unsorted entries
console.log(sorted);
```